Grafana: check HTTP resopnse code from external HTTP service
my application uses Grafana for alerting. But one of alerts (it shows not-consumed queue of messages) works wrong. It triggered when application is starting and when  messages can't be read.
Also app has API, which shows it state (200ok - started, 400 - starting)
How can I use my only code-returning REST API in grafana alerts to exclude unnecessary triggering?
I tried to find any datasource plugins, but it didn't success (f.e. Grafana HTTP API is for going to grafana, not for any URL)
Thanks for answers
